# Fill the area under curve in matlab plot3

Tags: matlab, plot

I have plots like this one:

[image]

and I need the areas under the curves to be white (the peaks not transparent). This is done by `plot3`. Is there a way to e.g. use `fill3` for such a purpose? I am asking cause I assume this must have been solved.

Comment: Try `surf` rather than `plot3`?

Comment: Sadly, I need to have the grid in only one dimension.

Comment: In what form is your data (or maybe give some example data?)

Comment: Per slice, you could do `fill3([x,x(1)],[y,y(1)],[z,z(1)],'w');`.  Albeit this produces a line along the bottom of the patch, which I don't know how to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small tricks using `plot3` and `surf` together. I use a white surface to hide the unwanted lines:

```
%Data generation
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(50);

%First we plot the surface
h = surf(X,Y,Z);
%We change the view (optionnal)
view(45,30);
%The plot become white
colormap([1,1,1])
h.EdgeColor = 'None';
%And now we plot our 3D lines.
hold on 
plot3(X,Y,Z,'b');
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]